# How to insert (instead redefine) context menu item in MAUI.NET control

Tags: contextmenu, maui, menuitem, flyout, right-mouse-button

I did a context menu for the control as described in tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/context-menu
It works perfect.

```
<Entry ...>
    <FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout>
        <MenuFlyout>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="..." Command="..." CommandParameter="..." />
        </MenuFlyout>
    </FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout>
</Entry>
```

But Entry itself has some context menu like copy etc. by standard.
When I did my one. I have removed the original collection.

I am looking for some easy way (instead of redoing standard behaviour) that allows to insert my one context menu item to the standard list of them. Would appreciate any hint.

Comment: Not possible. As it says in a large yellow box in that link: *WARNING: It's not currently possible to add items to, or remove items from, the MenuFlyout at runtime.*

Comment: This is not supported on in the maui for now. And this can be achieved in the native mac either.